# Java-Oracle Inserting a Record

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sql-insert

I want to insert a record on my database from text fields but it doesn't work.I am using Oracle 10g.I am new to all of this. My whole code is here but the part that doesn't work is private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) button code:

```
    package project1;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
    import static project1.InsertFrame.connection;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


    public class CRUD extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    //static Connection connection = null; 
         //Connection connection = null; 

          public CRUD() {

                     try {
                  initComponents();
                  String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
                  Class.forName(driverName);
                  String serverName = "192.168.0.2";
                  String portNumber = "1521";
                  String sid = "XE";
                  String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+serverName+":"+portNumber+":"+sid;
                  String userName = "HR";
                  String password = "hr";
                         try {
                             connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
                         } catch (SQLException ex) {
                             Logger.getLogger(CRUD.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                         }
                      try {
             String temp="";
             Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT URUN_TIPI FROM KART");


           while(rs.next()) // dönebildiği süre boyunca
           {
               String s = rs.getString("URUN_TIPI") ; //kolon isimleri oluşturuldu
               temp+=s+"_";
           }        

           Object [] tem_obj;

           tem_obj=temp.split("_");
           listOgrenciler.setListData(tem_obj);

       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(edit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

          } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(CRUD.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }    


             listOgrenciler.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

               @Override
               public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
                   if (!arg0.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                       try {
                         Statement stmtx = connection.createStatement();
                           Object[] sss=listOgrenciler.getSelectedValues();
                         String swhere="" ;
                         for (int i = 0; i < sss.length; i++) {
                               swhere+=sss[i].toString()+",";
                               }
                            swhere=swhere.substring(0,swhere.length()-1);
                         ResultSet rsx = stmtx.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM KART where URUN_TIPI in ('"+swhere+"')") ;
                         String temp="";
                         while(rsx.next()) // dönebildiği süre boyunca
                           {
                               String s = " * "+rsx.getString("BOLGE")+" - "+rsx.getString("SEHIR")+" - "+rsx.getString("LOKASYON")+" - "+rsx.getString("SERI_NO")+" - "+rsx.getString("URUN_TIPI")+" - "+rsx.getString("URUN_KODU")+" - "+rsx.getString("FAZ")+" - "+rsx.getString("SEVK_TARIH")+" - "+rsx.getString("ACIKLAMA")   ; //kolon isimleri oluşturuldu
                               temp+=s+"_";
                           }        

                             Object [] tem_obj;
                             tem_obj=temp.split("_");
                           String ara="";
                             for (int i = 0; i < tem_obj.length; i++) {
                               ara+=tem_obj[i].toString()+"\n";
                             }
                            texttoarea.setText(ara);

                       } catch (SQLException ex) 
                       {
                           Logger.getLogger(edit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                       }         
                   }
               }
           });



        }
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        try{

      String sqlInsert="INSERT INTO KART VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

      PreparedStatement psta=connection.preparedStatement(sqlInsert);
      psta.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
      psta.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
      psta.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());
      psta.setString(4, jTextField4.getText());
      psta.setString(5, jTextField5.getText());
      psta.setString(6, jTextField6.getText());
      psta.setString(7, jTextField7.getText());
      psta.setString(8, jTextField8.getText());
      psta.setString(9, jTextField9.getText());
      psta.setString(10, jTextField10.getText());

      psta.execute();
      psta.close();
      }
      catch(Exception e)
              {
              System.out.println(e.getCause());
              }
    } 
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CRUD.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CRUD.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CRUD.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CRUD.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CRUD().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JScrollBar jScrollBar2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField10;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField8;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField9;
    private javax.swing.JList listOgrenciler;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea texttoarea;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I can't add photos but my records have both numbers and letters like "SNS112468698" and "08ARTVIN_IL". It says cannot find symbol preparedStatement.I changed it to psta but it doesn't work.What is the problem ? Thank you very much already.

Comment: `What is the problem ?` - What is the error you get?

Comment: are you able to `fetch` the data prior to `insertion` ?

Comment: It says cannot find symbol preparedStatement.I changed it to psta but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post error stack trace.

Comment: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method preparedStatement(String)
  location: variable connection of type Connection

Comment: @Andreas has your answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cannot find symbol symbol:
method preparedStatement(String)
location: variable connection of type Connection
```

The method is called `prepareStatement`, not `preparedStatement` (note the d).

See also the [java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement() Javadoc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29)